# How do I measure the total time from the beginning to the end of the visit on page with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to find how much time has passed from the beginning to the end of the visit on page. I have a theory which is that, function get the time which comes by end of load, then when user leaved function also get leaving time and it calculates this times yet I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to track when the user loads the page and when the user leaves? PHP alone will not be able to do this, you'll have to implement some javascript as well.

Comment: Actually I can get the time by javascript. I should make more effort to do get the time as soon as page loaded.

Comment: Why don't you use Google Analytics? I'd really good, its free and very easy to implement. There you'll see the time spend on site for each visitor.

Comment: @MarcusLind It should be noticed that Google's time-on-site is not a great indicator. They measure time between pageviews, so the last one never counts. If a user bounces, time on site is zero in GA. http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-time-on-page-session-duration/

Answer (score 0):

Get time using javascript when page loads and store the variable in session, and detect the page close event in js and store it in another variable so that you have the page load and unload time in two variables.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language, so your code only runs on the server. You can however use JavaScript to repeatedly run some code that invokes a PHP script that updates a `last_seen` value in a session variable for the page.

For example you could try something like this...

Example PHP snippet in `home_page.php` (PHP part)

```
<?php
    $pn = "home_page";
    session_start(); //needed for $_SESSION
    $_SESSION["visit"][pn]=["first_seen"=>time(),"last_seen"=>time()];
?>
```

Example JavaScript snippet in `home_page.php` (JavaScript part, assuming JQuery)

```
<script>
    var pn = "home_page";
    setInterval(function(){ // every 1 second
        $.get( "time_keeper.php?page="+pn); //don't care about success
    }, 1000); // precision of 1 second
</script>
```

Example `time_keeper.php` PHP script

```
<?php
    session_start(); //needed for $_SESSION
    $_SESSION["visit"][$_GET["page"] ?? "404"]["last_seen"]=time()];
?>
```

Example of a `see_time.php` PHP script that outputs the time spent on a  specific page

```
<?php // usage: `see_time.php?page=home_page
    session_start(); //needed for $_SESSION
    $t=$_SESSION["visit"][$_GET["page"] ?? "404"]];
    $z=$t["last_seen"]-$t["first_seen"];
    echo "You've been there for $z seconds.";
?>
```

`home_page` is the name of your page: change it to be uniqe for every additional page, as needed.

Comment: I looking for 'last_seen' in web now.

Comment: I have run codes yet I guess it prints miliseconds on screen. Can I set it to the database with `substr($z,8);` ?

Comment: using $z directly is faster

Comment: I did it with division to 60. I think setInterval runs with dynamic seconds. To illustrate when I open the tab which displays my site in 34 of seconds, function's start second becomes 34. How do I make it 0 at the beginning?

Comment: with the method I provided the visit time starts when the browser requests the page, so a certain delay is introduced. If you want to set the starting time from javascript you can make another php script (let's name it `time_keeper2.php`) with the code from `time_keeper.php` and replace `last_seen` with `first_seen`. Then in the html add another line to the javascript code above:`$.get( "time_keeper2.php?page="+pn);`